# Laravel return category if products exists

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
$categories = Category::with('products')->where('parent_id', null)->paginate(15);
```

How I can return on variable `categories` categories where products exists?

I think that need use whereHas:

```
    $categories = Category::with('products')->where('parent_id', null)->whereHas('products', function($prods) { return ! $prods->isEmpty() })->paginate(15);
```

Please help resolve it.

Model Category:

```
    public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id')->withoutGlobalScope('active');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Comment: `parent_id` is in product table?

Comment: nope, this column of category

Answer (score 1):

you can use `has` function as per [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) (Querying Relationship Existence)

`$categories = Category::with('products')->has('products')->where('parent_id', null)->paginate(15);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use has function to get records where products available like :

```
$categories = Category::has('products')
                       ->whereNull('parent_id')
                       ->paginate(15);
```